# Powerapps: An error occurred on the server, Office 365 Dynamics entity data source

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps

I'm trying to use a Dynamics 365 entity within a Data table however this hangs as shown in the screenshots below.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Other entities work fine except this one.